# Gorilla mux can't separate two routes

Tags: go, url-routing, gorilla

I am using Gorilla and i discovered that gorilla router can't resolve two routes. I am using trailing slash at the end of each URL. Consider following routing table:

```golang
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    baseUri, _ := stringFormatter.Format("/api/{0}", apiVersion)
    // function resource
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/", webApiContext.GetAllFunctions).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/find/", webApiContext.FindFunctions).Methods("GET").Queries("query", "{query}")
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/{id}/", webApiContext.GetFunctionById).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/{id}/body/", webApiContext.GetFunctionBodyById).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/", webApiContext.CreateFunction).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/{id}/", webApiContext.UpdateFunction).Methods("PUT")
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/{id}/", webApiContext.DeleteFunction).Methods("DELETE")
```

Gorilla can't separate these two routes GET /function/{id}/ and GET /function/find/?query={query}. If I am placing a **find method** *above* **getting function by id**, find handler ***invokes for the both find & get function by id URLs***.

This could be resolved by ***remove trailing slash from*** one of these URLs i.e for find URL declaration. But I am ***have to use StrictSlash(true)*** function that makes ***unable to use that hack*** with URL declaration.

Could you please help to solve  issue with proper URL declaration.

Comment: What format are you `id`s?  Are you sure `find` is not a valid potential `id`? If so, you can use a regex to validate the `id` so "find" no longer passes.

Comment: id s are integers. However path variables i am getting from string, maybe if i could somehow affect on HandleFunc resolve process i could solve my issue. But where your suggest to use regex, could you show me example, please.

Comment: You can see a few examples in the readme of the mux repository: https://github.com/gorilla/mux like `{id:[0-9]+}` to match a decimal number id

Comment: @HymnsForDisco, yes i'll try it in monday, seems this could solve my problem. Thanks you!

Comment: @HymnsForDisco, thanks you, you suggestion helped me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hymns For Disco noticed to solve this issue we have to path variable check inside curved bracket using regular expressions, therefore proper routing table should look like^

```golang
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/", webApiContext.GetAllFunctions).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/find/", webApiContext.FindFunctions).Methods("GET").Queries("query", "{query}")
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/{id:[0-9]+}/", webApiContext.GetFunctionById).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/{id:[0-9]+}/body/", webApiContext.GetFunctionBodyById).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/", webApiContext.CreateFunction).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/{id:[0-9]+}/", webApiContext.UpdateFunction).Methods("PUT")
    router.HandleFunc(baseUri + "/function/{id:[0-9]+}/", webApiContext.DeleteFunction).Methods("DELETE")
```